# Pass Parameter from controller to Component in Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I have been given a task to maintain a cakephp app. There is an issue with uploading files to server. All these time we were using AWS S3 Bucket now we want upload it to our own file server.  The coding part was done by my ex-colleague.

I am trying a simple stuff I want to send fileName from my controller to Component files called S3.

Coding which is done is like this:

```
$this->S3->uploadFile($this->request->data('upload.tmp_name'),$fileKey);
```

In S3Component file:

I have written the following:

```
 public function uploadFile($filePath, $fileKey, $metaData = [])
    {
          $fileUtility = new FileUtility(1024 * 1024, array("ppt", "pdf"));
          return $fileUtility->uploadFile($_FILES[$fileKey], $filePath);
    }
```

Now how do I pass the values in S3->uploadFile correctly to reflect the uploadfile function S3Compontent file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you can be bothered refactoring, you could try Flysystem, a file management package installable through composer. https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/

The nice thing about it is, you just swap an S3 adapter for a local adapter, ftp adapter, etc (there are a few!), and none of your code needs to change!

For instance:

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use League\Flysystem\AwsS3v3\AwsS3Adapter;
use League\Flysystem\Filesystem;

$client = S3Client::factory([
    'credentials' => [
        'key'    => 'your-key',
        'secret' => 'your-secret',
    ],
    'region' => 'your-region',
    'version' => 'latest|version',
]);

$adapter = new AwsS3Adapter($client, 'your-bucket-name', 'optional/path/prefix');
```

And to create a Local Adapter:

```
use League\Flysystem\Filesystem;
use League\Flysystem\Adapter\Local;

$adapter = new Local(__DIR__.'/path/to/root');
$filesystem = new Filesystem($adapter);
```

Then, you can make identical calls to `$filesystem` like these:

```
$filesystem->write('path/to/file.txt', 'contents');
$contents = $filesystem->read('path/to/file.txt');
$filesystem->delete('path/to/file.txt');
$filesystem->copy('filename.txt', 'duplicate.txt');
```

Check out the API here: https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/api/